# Growth of Branching Processes (Galton-Watson Process)

Tags: probability

I am looking for a book/paper that studies questions as the following for branching processes:

> The probability that there are at least X individuals in the branching
>   process after t steps is at least y.

I usually only find theorems stating asymptotic behaviour for t approaching infinity. I want to ask the question for a given fixed t (and fixed X).

I  even have the setting that there is a finite set of nonzero branching probabilities and I am not sure whether this helps.

Someone must have studied a similar question.